# Hibernate mapping "class" must match

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have next message error with red line under

```
The content of element type "class" must match "(meta*,subselect?,cache?,synchronize*,comment?,tuplizer*,(id|
 composite-id),discriminator?,natural-id?,(version|timestamp)?,(property|many-to-one|one-to-one|component|
 dynamic-component|properties|any|map|set|list|bag|idbag|array|primitive-array)*,((join*,subclass*)|joined-
 subclass*|union-subclass*),loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,filter*,fetch-profile*,resultset*,(query|sql-
 query)*)".
```

I'm trying to create `POJO` classes with mapping file of the next part of Oracle HR Scheme.

```
Employees
Employee_id
first name
last_name
....
department_id
```

**many to one**

```
Departments
department_id
department_name
manager_id
location_id
```

**many to one**

```
Locations
location_id
...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping> 
<class name = "employee.Department" table="DEPARTMENTS">
<meta attribute="class-description">This class contains the department  records.</meta>
<id name = "id" type = "int" column="department_id"/>     
<many-to_one name="location" column = "location_id" 
        class = "employee.Location" not-null = "true"/>
</class>   
<class name = "employee.Location" table="LOCATIONS">
<meta attribute="class-description">This class contains the locations records.</meta>
<id name = "id" type = "int" column="location_id"/>
<property name="streetAdress" column = "street_adress" type = "string"/>   
<property name="postalCode" column = "postal_code" type = "string"/>   
<property name="city" column = "city" type = "string"/>   
<property name="stateProvince" column = "state_province" type = "string"/>   
<property name="country_id" column = "country_id" type = "string"/>   
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by the error message, the `<class>` tag can have a variety of children but `<many-to_one>` (note the <kbd>_</kbd>) is not an allowed child.